# QWidget next to the tabs of QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt and C++, is it possible to place a QWidget next to the tabs of a QTabWidget?

To clarify what I mean the following picture:[image: An example program with a QTabWidget]

The red rectangle in this picture belongs to QTabWidget, but is not used because all the tabs are small enough to not need it. Would it be possible to place another QWidget here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QTabWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) is easy-to-use combination of a [`QTabBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html) and a [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

So instead of using `QTabWidget`, you can use `QTabBar` and `QStackedWidget` directly. Just connect the [`QTabBar::currentChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#currentChanged) signal to the [`QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) slot and you'll get the same functionality. The advantage is that you can place the two freely on your form. You can place them in a grid layout and place any additional widgets next to the `QTabBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I used following stylesheet when I combined `QTabBar` with `QStackedWidget`. However, it is missing the border. I didn't know how to style the top of the page just under the bar (without the border appearing under selected tab).

```
QTabBar::tab { 
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
}
QTabBar::tab:selected { 
    background-color: white; 
}
QTabBar::tab:!selected { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 240); \
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); 
}
QStackedWidget { 
    background-color: white; 
}
```